# Count HQL result where GROUP BY is used

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an hql query where I need to group them in some way. So this query looks almost like this:

```
SELECT a1,a2,a3
FROM tablename
GROUP BY a1,a2,a3;
```

I want to count result of this query but without using subquery (as far as I know HQL can't select from subquery):

```
/* I don't want to do it in this way because of HQL */
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT a1,a2,a3
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY a1,a2,a3
);
```

So is there some way to count grouped result without subquery?